# Summing values from Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using Python to sum random star spectra to increase their signal to noise ratio. One of the keywords of these spectra header contains the integration time for the spectrum. When I sum the spectra I want the keyword of the resulting spectrum to be updated with the sum of the integration times of each spectrum I used. For that, I use the following code:

```
for kk in range(0,NumberOfSpectra):             # main cycle
       TotalIntegrationTime = 0.0
       for item in RandomSpectraList:                       # secondary cycle
           SpectrumHeader = SpectraFullList[item]['head']         #1
           TotalIntegrationTime += SpectrumHeader['EXPTIME']

       SpectrumHeader['EXPTIME'] = TotalIntegrationTime               #2

    SaveHeaderFunction(SpectrumHeader, kk)
```

the problem I am having, is that when the main cycle loops, `SpectrumHeader` does not get reset when I re-assign it in #1 and shows the value it had in #2. Any ideas on why this happens and how to fix it?

`NumberOfSpectra` is provided by the user, `RandomSpectraList` is a list of random spectra by name. `SpectraFullList` contains the spectra and has keys 'head' and 'spec'.

Comment: #1 should reassign SpectrumHeader. Can you give a short example of input/output ?

Comment: You seem to be missing some use of `kk`. The current code is equivalent to `sum(SpectraFullList[item]['head']['EXPTIME'] for item in RandomSpectraList)` done `kk` times... which is probably not what you intended. Nothing changes between the iterations of the main cycle.

Comment: @Bitwise: My input will be multiple fits images,  I use pyfits to extract them into a dictionary (SpectraFullList[FitsImageName]['head'], SpectraFullList[item]['spec']). The output I get is that the first instance of SpectrumHeader['EXPTIME'] in the secondary loop will be the correct one for the spectra in consideration, but on the following instances it will be the sum of the last run of the secondary loop.

Comment: @viraptor: kk will be used on the filename where the spectrum is saved, I require 'NumberOfSpectra' sums of random spectra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware of the fact during line #2, SpectrumHeader still points to an element of SpectraFullList?  They are the really the same object.
So, when executing line #2 you are essentially modifying SpectraFullList.
I guess that is not what you want and it may be the cause of your problem.

In order to solve it, insert the following line before #2:

```
SpectrumHeader = SpectraFullList[item]['head'].copy()
```